# How to make != become =/= in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I watched a webinar and I found the speaker's editor showing the `!=` as `=/=`.

[image]

## Question

How to get such a feature in VS 2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a font that supports ligatures. Try, for example, [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode).

In order to enable Fira Code in VS2017, see the [instructions](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Visual-Studio-2017-Instructions).